# fetch best seller of a category for a particular month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the 3 best selling item for a particular category (if there is any sold item of course) for that particular month.

When i ran

```
SELECT  io.item_name,  
    COUNT(io.item_name) AS number_sold  
FROM  category_tbl AS c   
    LEFT JOIN item_out_tbl AS io ON io.category_id = c.category_id
        AND c.category_id = '$category_id'
    LEFT JOIN sales_tbl    AS sa ON io.item_id = sa.item_id                               
        AND '$current_month'=MONTH(date_sold) 
GROUP BY  io.item_name 
ORDER BY number_sold DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

I get results even though those MONTH(date_sold) are not equals to the `$current_month`, `'$current_month'=MONTH(date_sold)` is disregarded. I expect an empty result since I don't have `item_name` that match its `item_sold` for that `$current_month`

Comment: `'$current_month'=MONTH(date_sold)` swap that around: `MONTH(date_sold)='$current_month'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `left join`s seem unnecessary.  The better way to fix your problem is just to use inner joins:

```
SELECT  io.item_name, COUNT(io.item_name) AS number_sold  
FROM item_out_tbl io JOIN
     category_tbl c   
     ON io.category_id = c.category_id AND c.category_id = '$category_id' JOIN
     sales_tbl sa
     ON io.item_id = sa.item_id AND                            
        $current_month' = MONTH(date_sold) 
GROUP BY io.item_name 
ORDER BY number_sold DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are using `left join` so you get nulls from joined table if equivalent value not exists so just add `WHERE sa.item_id IS NOT NULL` clause:

```
SELECT  io.item_name,  
    COUNT(io.item_name) AS number_sold  
FROM  category_tbl AS c   
    LEFT JOIN item_out_tbl AS io ON io.category_id = c.category_id
        AND c.category_id = '$category_id'
    LEFT JOIN sales_tbl    AS sa ON io.item_id = sa.item_id                               
        AND '$current_month'=MONTH(date_sold) 
WHERE sa.item_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  io.item_name 
ORDER BY number_sold DESC 
LIMIT 3
```